# plugin audio/x-gst-fourcc-mp3 decoder

Tags: sound, plugins, mp3

i am trying to convert VOB to YOUTUBEHD file on VLC player, the conversion is going without problems but the result is this message: Videos requires to install plugins to play media files of the following type: audio/x-gst-fourcc-mp3 decoder. I can see the videos soundless. 
  My configuration is this> OS Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, Memory 3.8gb, Processor Intel I34005u 1.7ghzx4, Os type 64bites, Graphics Intel. 
  Please someone tell where to find and how to install the plugin audio/x-gst-fourcc-mp3 decoder?

Answer (score 0):

This can simply be solved by going to AUDIO CODEC tab in VLC and mark tick over the KEEP ORIGINAL AUDIO TRACK followed by your other vlc settings steps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer i will try that.